# PullAsync Silently fails

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I'm using .Net backend Azure Mobile Services on a Windows Phone app. I've added the offline services that Azure Mobile Services provides to the code for using SQLite.
The app makes successful Push calls (I can see the data in my database and they exist in the local db created by Azure Mobile Offline Services).
In PullAsync calls, it makes the right call to the Service (The table controller) and Service calculates the results and returns multiple rows from the database. However, the results are lost on the way. My client App is getting an empty Json message (I double checked it with fiddler).

```
  IMobileServiceSyncTable<Contact> _contactTable;
  /* Table Initialization Code */
  var contactQuery = _contactTable.Where(c => c.Owner == Service.UserId);
  await _contactTable.PullAsync("c0", contactQuery);
  var contacts = await _contactTable.Select(c => c).ToListAsync();
```

Any suggestion on how I can investigate this issue?

**Update**

The code above is using incremental sync by passing query ID of "c0". Passing null to PullAsync for the first argument disables incremental sync and makes it return all the rows, which is working as expected.

```
await _contactTable.PullAsync(null, contactQuery);
```

But I'm still not able to get incremental sync to return the rows when app is reinstalled.

Comment: It will appear that there are rows returned if you put a breakpoint in your controller. However, it returns an IQueryable that is later modified through WebAPI filters that the .NET backend had defined. What is returned by the controller is not necessarily what is sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with this, I found that the problem was caused by me making different sync calls the same table.
In my App I have a list of local users, and I only want to pull down the details for the users I have locally.

So I was issuing this call in a loop

```
userTbl.PullAsync("Updating User Table", userTbl.CreateQuery().Where(x => x.Id == grp1.UserId || x.Id == LocalUser.Id)
```

What I founds is that by Adding the user Id to the call I over came the issue:

```
userTbl.PullAsync("User-" + grp1.UserId, userTbl.CreateQuery().Where(x => x.Id == grp1.UserId || x.Id == LocalUser.Id)
```

As a side note, depending on your id format, the string you supply to the query has to be less than 50 characters in length.

:-)

Comment: That's right--you need to use a different query name (the first parameter) for each unique query in your app. Here's a documentation link with more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/#summary

Answer (score 0):

The .NET backend is set up to not send JSON for fields that have the default value (e.g., zero for integers). There's a bug with the interaction with the offline SDK. As a workaround, you should set up the default value handling in your WebConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
```

You should also try doing similar queries using the online SDK (use IMobileServiceTable instead of sync table)--that will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks Donna, the fields don't have the default value. I replaced "c0" with null to skip the sessions and get all the rows and it worked as expected.

Comment: Oh, yes, this is because you are using incremental sync. When you specify a query ID, the SDK uses that to add an updatedAt clause to the REST query. Those rows should all be in your local table, unless you manually changed something in the database.

Comment: Yeah, if I uninstall the app (from the emulator) and reinstall it again it skips the rows.

Comment: That doesn't seem right--the local database is what contains the incremental sync information. If the database is gone, so would the last modified timestamp. What kind of query do you see being sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very useful tool for debugging the deserialisation: use a custom delegating handler in your `MobileServiceClient` instance.

```
public class MyHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Request happens here
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // Read response content and try to deserialise here...
        ...

        return response;
    }
}

// In your mobile client code:
var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net", new MyHandler());
```

This helped me to solve my issues. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/16/adjusting-the-http-call-with-azure-mobile-apps/ for more details.